# Why am I only seeing white screen in TFT 1.44 ST7735?

Tags: tft

I just bought the 3rd TFT and in all my attempts I get the white screen I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

This time I bought it and **followed their instruction's** [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-1-44-color-tft-with-micro-sd-socket/overview)

I created this schematic using Fritzing which is the one I'm using but still I am getting the white screen again

[image]

Here are some [Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF9mV.jpg) of what is the **TFT displaying**.

Finally, I did also used the recommended testing code which is listed in: 
File > Examples > Adafruit ST7735 and ST7789 library > graphicstest

Also, I have did commented the slightly changed. So this is the code I'm using:

```c
/**************************************************************************
  This is a library for several Adafruit displays based on ST77* drivers.

  Works with the Adafruit 1.8" TFT Breakout w/SD card
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/358
  The 1.8" TFT shield
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/802
  The 1.44" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088
  as well as Adafruit raw 1.8" TFT display
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/618

  Check out the links above for our tutorials and wiring diagrams.
  These displays use SPI to communicate, 4 or 5 pins are required to
  interface (RST is optional).

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 **************************************************************************/

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_HALLOWING
  #define TFT_CS        39 // Hallowing display control pins: chip select
  #define TFT_RST       37 // Display reset
  #define TFT_DC        38 // Display data/command select
  #define TFT_BACKLIGHT  7 // Display backlight pin
#elif defined(ESP8266)
  #define TFT_CS         4
  #define TFT_RST        16                                            
  #define TFT_DC         5
#else
  // For the breakout board, you can use any 2 or 3 pins.
  // These pins will also work for the 1.8" TFT shield.
  #define TFT_CS        10
  #define TFT_RST        9 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
  #define TFT_DC         8
#endif

// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 (including HalloWing) use:
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// For 1.54" TFT with ST7789:
//Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// OPTION 2 lets you interface the display using ANY TWO or THREE PINS,
// tradeoff being that performance is not as fast as hardware SPI above.
//#define TFT_MOSI 11  // Data out
//#define TFT_SCLK 13  // Clock out
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_RST);

float p = 3.1415926;

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print(F("Hello! ST77xx TFT Test"));

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_HALLOWING
  // HalloWing is a special case. It uses a ST7735R display just like the
  // breakout board, but the orientation and backlight control are different.
  tft.initR(INITR_HALLOWING);        // Initialize HalloWing-oriented screen
  pinMode(TFT_BACKLIGHT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(TFT_BACKLIGHT, HIGH); // Backlight on
#else
  // Use this initializer if using a 1.8" TFT screen:
 // tft.initR(INITR_BLACKTAB);      // Init ST7735S chip, black tab

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.44" TFT:
  tft.initR(INITR_144GREENTAB); // Init ST7735R chip, green tab

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 0.96" 180x60 TFT:
  //tft.initR(INITR_MINI160x80);  // Init ST7735S mini display

  // OR use this initializer (uncomment) if using a 1.54" 240x240 TFT:
  //tft.init(240, 240);           // Init ST7789 240x240
#endif

  Serial.println(F("Initialized"));

  uint16_t time = millis();
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  time = millis() - time;

  Serial.println(time, DEC);
  delay(500);

  // large block of text
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  testdrawtext("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur adipiscing ante sed nibh tincidunt feugiat. Maecenas enim massa, fringilla sed malesuada et, malesuada sit amet turpis. Sed porttitor neque ut ante pretium vitae malesuada nunc bibendum. Nullam aliquet ultrices massa eu hendrerit. Ut sed nisi lorem. In vestibulum purus a tortor imperdiet posuere. ", ST77XX_WHITE);
  delay(1000);

  // tft print function!
  tftPrintTest();
  delay(4000);

  // a single pixel
  tft.drawPixel(tft.width()/2, tft.height()/2, ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);

  // line draw test
  testlines(ST77XX_YELLOW);
  delay(500);

  // optimized lines
  testfastlines(ST77XX_RED, ST77XX_BLUE);
  delay(500);

  testdrawrects(ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);

  testfillrects(ST77XX_YELLOW, ST77XX_MAGENTA);
  delay(500);

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  testfillcircles(10, ST77XX_BLUE);
  testdrawcircles(10, ST77XX_WHITE);
  delay(500);

  testroundrects();
  delay(500);

  testtriangles();
  delay(500);

  mediabuttons();
  delay(500);

  Serial.println("done");
  delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  tft.invertDisplay(true);
  delay(500);
  tft.invertDisplay(false);
  delay(500);
}

void testlines(uint16_t color) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, 0, x, tft.height()-1, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, 0, tft.width()-1, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, 0, x, tft.height()-1, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, 0, 0, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, tft.height()-1, x, 0, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(0, tft.height()-1, tft.width()-1, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }

  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, tft.height()-1, x, 0, color);
    delay(0);
  }
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=6) {
    tft.drawLine(tft.width()-1, tft.height()-1, 0, y, color);
    delay(0);
  }
}

void testdrawtext(char *text, uint16_t color) {
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(color);
  tft.setTextWrap(true);
  tft.print(text);
}

void testfastlines(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height(); y+=5) {
    tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, tft.width(), color1);
  }
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=5) {
    tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, tft.height(), color2);
  }
}

void testdrawrects(uint16_t color) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width(); x+=6) {
    tft.drawRect(tft.width()/2 -x/2, tft.height()/2 -x/2 , x, x, color);
  }
}

void testfillrects(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  for (int16_t x=tft.width()-1; x > 6; x-=6) {
    tft.fillRect(tft.width()/2 -x/2, tft.height()/2 -x/2 , x, x, color1);
    tft.drawRect(tft.width()/2 -x/2, tft.height()/2 -x/2 , x, x, color2);
  }
}

void testfillcircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  for (int16_t x=radius; x < tft.width(); x+=radius*2) {
    for (int16_t y=radius; y < tft.height(); y+=radius*2) {
      tft.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }
}

void testdrawcircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  for (int16_t x=0; x < tft.width()+radius; x+=radius*2) {
    for (int16_t y=0; y < tft.height()+radius; y+=radius*2) {
      tft.drawCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }
}

void testtriangles() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  int color = 0xF800;
  int t;
  int w = tft.width()/2;
  int x = tft.height()-1;
  int y = 0;
  int z = tft.width();
  for(t = 0 ; t <= 15; t++) {
    tft.drawTriangle(w, y, y, x, z, x, color);
    x-=4;
    y+=4;
    z-=4;
    color+=100;
  }
}

void testroundrects() {
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  int color = 100;
  int i;
  int t;
  for(t = 0 ; t <= 4; t+=1) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int w = tft.width()-2;
    int h = tft.height()-2;
    for(i = 0 ; i <= 16; i+=1) {
      tft.drawRoundRect(x, y, w, h, 5, color);
      x+=2;
      y+=3;
      w-=4;
      h-=6;
      color+=1100;
    }
    color+=100;
  }
}

void tftPrintTest() {
  tft.setTextWrap(false);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setCursor(0, 30);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_RED);
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_YELLOW);
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_BLUE);
  tft.setTextSize(4);
  tft.print(1234.567);
  delay(1500);
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.setTextSize(0);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.print(p, 6);
  tft.println(" Want pi?");
  tft.println(" ");
  tft.print(8675309, HEX); // print 8,675,309 out in HEX!
  tft.println(" Print HEX!");
  tft.println(" ");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.println("Sketch has been");
  tft.println("running for: ");
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_MAGENTA);
  tft.print(millis() / 1000);
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.print(" seconds.");
}

void mediabuttons() {
  // play
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);
  tft.fillRoundRect(25, 10, 78, 60, 8, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_RED);
  delay(500);
  // pause
  tft.fillRoundRect(25, 90, 78, 60, 8, ST77XX_WHITE);
  tft.fillRoundRect(39, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_GREEN);
  tft.fillRoundRect(69, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_GREEN);
  delay(500);
  // play color
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_BLUE);
  delay(50);
  // pause color
  tft.fillRoundRect(39, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_RED);
  tft.fillRoundRect(69, 98, 20, 45, 5, ST77XX_RED);
  // play color
  tft.fillTriangle(42, 20, 42, 60, 90, 40, ST77XX_GREEN);
}
```

Please don't mark this question as duplicated because I looked at the other guy he/she was using different guide.. the one I'm using is posted by the company I purchased the TFT from.

Comment: White screen = display not being initialized. Triple check your wiring and code.

Comment: did you insert SD card? if yes, remove it

Comment: Juraj - Yes I did it with and without but the output still same. I don't know very frustrating.

Comment: Majenko - Thank you for the comment but I'm not expert and I did same as I should be followed  by the guide multiple times and I did upload some photos of what the wiring... I'm sorry I'm not sure what to do next

Comment: is your Arduino here the Arduino Micro too as in the next question?

Comment: @Glorfindel Hey if you still looking for questions to edit, then go to my recent question asked, I'm sure you will find a common or period missing to fix. I guess that is your job! Way to go!

Comment: @Juraj Yes same one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest some changes in your code i.e.

Your Code:

```
/**************************************************************************
  This is a library for several Adafruit displays based on ST77* drivers.

  Works with the Adafruit 1.8" TFT Breakout w/SD card
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/358
  The 1.8" TFT shield
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/802
  The 1.44" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088
  as well as Adafruit raw 1.8" TFT display
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/618

  Check out the links above for our tutorials and wiring diagrams.
  These displays use SPI to communicate, 4 or 5 pins are required to
  interface (RST is optional).

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 **************************************************************************/

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>

#ifdef ADAFRUIT_HALLOWING
  #define TFT_CS        39 // Hallowing display control pins: chip select
  #define TFT_RST       37 // Display reset
  #define TFT_DC        38 // Display data/command select
  #define TFT_BACKLIGHT  7 // Display backlight pin
#elif defined(ESP8266)
  #define TFT_CS         4
  #define TFT_RST        16                                            
  #define TFT_DC         5
#else
  // For the breakout board, you can use any 2 or 3 pins.
  // These pins will also work for the 1.8" TFT shield.
  #define TFT_CS        10
  #define TFT_RST        9 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
  #define TFT_DC         8
#endif

// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 (including HalloWing) use:
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// For 1.54" TFT with ST7789:
//Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// OPTION 2 lets you interface the display using ANY TWO or THREE PINS,
// tradeoff being that performance is not as fast as hardware SPI above.
//#define TFT_MOSI 11  // Data out
//#define TFT_SCLK 13  // Clock out
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_RST);
```

changes suggested:

```
/**************************************************************************
  This is a library for several Adafruit displays based on ST77* drivers.

  Works with the Adafruit 1.8" TFT Breakout w/SD card
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/358
  The 1.8" TFT shield
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/802
  The 1.44" TFT breakout
    ----> https://www.adafruit.com/product/2088
  as well as Adafruit raw 1.8" TFT display
    ----> http://www.adafruit.com/products/618

  Check out the links above for our tutorials and wiring diagrams.
  These displays use SPI to communicate, 4 or 5 pins are required to
  interface (RST is optional).

  Adafruit invests time and resources providing this open source code,
  please support Adafruit and open-source hardware by purchasing
  products from Adafruit!

  Written by Limor Fried/Ladyada for Adafruit Industries.
  MIT license, all text above must be included in any redistribution
 **************************************************************************/

#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>    // Core graphics library
#include <Adafruit_ST7735.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7735
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h> // Hardware-specific library for ST7789
#include <SPI.h>

  #define TFT_CS        10
  #define TFT_RST        9 // Or set to -1 and connect to Arduino RESET pin
  #define TFT_DC         8

// OPTION 1 (recommended) is to use the HARDWARE SPI pins, which are unique
// to each board and not reassignable. For Arduino Uno: MOSI = pin 11 and
// SCLK = pin 13. This is the fastest mode of operation and is required if
// using the breakout board's microSD card.

// For 1.44" and 1.8" TFT with ST7735 (including HalloWing) use:
//Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// For 1.54" TFT with ST7789:
//Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

// OPTION 2 lets you interface the display using ANY TWO or THREE PINS,
// tradeoff being that performance is not as fast as hardware SPI above.
#define TFT_MOSI 11  // Data out
#define TFT_SCLK 13  // Clock out
Adafruit_ST7735 tft = Adafruit_ST7735(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_SCLK, TFT_RST);
```

Replace your that part with one I suggested as **You commented tha SCK and MISO pins in your code so no data transfer is happening on those pins.** Secondly I made changes according to your hardware configuration as well.

Comment: You are a genius ... haha No more stupid white screen ... I see a colorful screen

Comment: I hope I will not be a bother. I just had a request and not sure if it could work. I was going to use MicroSD but since this has one, can I use it externally? like can I put .wav sound and play it in a speaker? Since you know the wiring I was hoping you could provide me with code which doses load sound file from that sd card and output to a speaker at maybe pin 3? This will help me a lot and make the project smaller so it can be wearable. Thank you

Comment: we don't provide code here, we can help you with you problem and provide solution for the problems but not the code.

Comment: alright I understand. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Maybe I guess I should ask this,  can I still use the built-in MicroSD externally or only it will be for loading images to the TFT?

Comment: I don't understand this **still use the built-in MicroSD externally**, please be clear about what are you looking for.

Comment: That TFT 1.44 has a chip for Micro card and they told me it is for loading images .bmp to the screen.. so I was wondering if I can store sound files .wav there and output it to a speaker in different pin  instead of buying this `Micro SD Card Breakout Board `  - hopefully I explained right sorry for my English.

Comment: Do you have exposed pins for Micro SD? If yes you can try.

Comment: I'm really not good with this stuff but anyway that is okay ha ha

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark it as the answer!

Comment: @Vaibhav, you solved this by switching to bit-banged SPI. you could not know this but a photo in next question revealed an Arduino Micro, not Nano

Comment: @Juraj what you guys talking about... you guys are way smart I don't understand these terms. It blacks me out!

Comment: the TFT library can work on any pins if you specify them. It will use software SPI. That is why it worked on 'wrong' pins.

Comment: Alright, I have made a lot of improvement and added stuff.. and now I don't understand why this line `USE_ARDUINO_INTERRUPTS true` case my **TFT** half-working. don't think you need my code but here is it `https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground/issues/101`

Comment: @Juraj I have another problem with the last question I asked in my profile